# Using ttk with Py2App

Tags: python, tkinter, py2app, ttk

I'm trying to figure out how to use Py2App to make one of my scripts less user hostile. The script is written using Tkinter using "notebook" from ttk, and I can't figure out how to include the ttk thing! It compiles as it should but when I try to run I get a console error: `_tkinter.TclError: can't find package tile`.

The problem can be replicated with:

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

from Tkinter import Tk
from ttk import Notebook

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui = Tk()
    gui.wm_title("Py2App testing")
    gui.wm_minsize(450, 300)
    main = Notebook(gui)
    main.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
    gui.mainloop()
```

I use a simple file which looks like:

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['test.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app',],
)
```

I've tried a number of combinations of `'packages': ['ttk']`, `'includes': ['ttk'],`, `setup_requires=['py2app', 'ttk'],`, but I can't get it to work so I figured maybe someone can explain how this actually works! =)

I don't know about tile either, how do I include that?